# DVL file format incorrect (Windows Driver) (Windows Hardware Lab Kit)

Tags: windows, driver, windows-driver

I have a problem with the Static Tools Logo Test of the Windows Hardware Lab Kit. The problem is that the driver test will fail because the DVL file format is incorrect on the x64.Semmle.Summary line. But I cannot edit this line of change the input because the DVL file is hash. A screenshot of the error in the HLK manager is displayed below

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7Lbe.png)

The input for this line is CodeQL. I have changed the version of the CodeQL already but this did not check the outcome.

How can I pass the Static Tools Logo Test when then generated input file is incorrect? Any ideas? If needed, I can supply more information.